# Wicket + Atmosphere + Guice

Tags: java, wicket, guice, atmosphere

I'm trying to configure Atmosphere and that is what I get when I post event to EventBus

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MeteorServlet not defined in web.xml
at org.atmosphere.cpr.Meteor.build(Meteor.java:170) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.8.jar:1.0.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.Meteor.build(Meteor.java:151) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.8.jar:1.0.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.Meteor.build(Meteor.java:137) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.8.jar:1.0.8]
at org.atmosphere.cpr.Meteor.build(Meteor.java:124) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.8.jar:1.0.8]
at org.apache.wicket.atmosphere.AtmosphereBehavior.onResourceRequested(AtmosphereBehavior.java:107) ~[wicket-atmosphere-0.7.jar:0.7]
... 56 common frames omitted
```

I use Wicket, this is AjaxButton onSubmit implementation:

```
public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
      EventBus.get().post(message.getModelObject());
}
```

I'm configuring Atmosphere using Guice. In my ServletModule implementation:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("applicationClassName", "org.mycompany.MyWebApplication");
            params.put(ApplicationConfig.PROPERTY_SERVLET_MAPPING, "/session/**");
            params.put(ApplicationConfig.PROPERTY_SESSION_SUPPORT, "true");
            params.put(ApplicationConfig.WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL, "org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.EchoProtocol");
            params.put(ApplicationConfig.BROADCAST_FILTER_CLASSES, "org.apache.wicket.atmosphere.TrackMessageSizeFilter");
            filter("/session/**").through(AtmosphereFilter.class, params);
```

This is my atmosphere.xml:

```
<atmosphere-handler context-root="/session/**"
    class-name="org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor">
</atmosphere-handler>
```

I want to configure filters programmatically, can I do it with atmosphere filters? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your web.xml?

Comment: <listener>
    <listener-class>org.mycompany.MyGuiceModule</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>guice.filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>guice.filter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

Comment: I know it's a bit late now, but the first error is you don't have the MeteorServlet or Atmosphere servlet defined in the web.xml. Check the sample here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.atmosphere.samples%22%20AND%20a%3A%22atmosphere-guice-chat%22

Comment: So, can't i define Atmosphere servlet in the guice module?

Comment: and can't i use wicket-atmosphere integration?

Comment: Should be able to. Did you see this example as well:
http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2009/12/17/using-google-guice-with-atmosphere/

Comment: Yes, I have already seen this example. My question is in using wicket-atmosphere with Guice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. Using `MeteorServlet` instead of `AtmosphereFilter` then an `atmosphere.xml` isn't needed and you should pass `WicketFilter` init params to the `MeteorServlet`.

Comment: Care to share your solution, e.g., how to let Guice instantiate the WicketFilter?

Comment: I was using MeteorServlet. You should declare filter mappings in GuiceServletContextListener, here is my solution: `new ServletModule { void configureServlets() { serve("/*").with(MeteorServlet.class, filterParams);} }`

Comment: Yes but in this setup, Atmosphere will instantiate a WicketFilter without using Guice (from the `filterName` parameter), so that you cannot use the injector for your WebApplication.  And in my experiments, I was consequently unable to use `guice.servlet` scopes such as `RequestScope`... Thanks anyway!